# Apache beam do all keys have to fit into memory on a worker

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Assuming I have an unbounded dataset with extremely high cardinity > 1,000,000,000 unique keys, lets say I want to count by key, lets say over fixed windows

My understanding the combine function will essentially maintain an accumulator on each machine in memory for each key.

**Question 1**

Is the above assumption correct or can workers flush out keys and accumulators to disk when under memory pressure

**Question 2 (assuming above correct)**

Assuming the data is not naturally partitioned (e.g reading from pubsub) would we run out of memory on each worker since every machine may in theory see every key and have to maintain an in memory structure for each key?

**Question 3 (assuming above correct)**

If we store the data on kafka and split up the data into partitions based on the key we are counting on. Assuming you have 1 beam worker reading from 1 partition then each worker only see a consistent subset of the keyspace. In this scenario would the memory use of the workers be any different?

Answer (score 0):

Beam is meant to be highly scalable; there are Beam pipelines that run on Dataflow with many trillions of unique keys.

When running a combining operation in Beam a table of keys and aggregated values is kept in memory, but when the table becomes full it is flushed to disk (well, technically, to shuffle) so it will not run out of memory. Another worker will read this data out of shuffle, one value at a time, to compute the final aggregate over all upstream worker outputs.

As for your other two questions, if your input is naturally partitioned by key such that each worker only sees a subset of keys it is possible that more combining could happen before the shuffle, leading to less data being shuffled, but this is by no means certain and the effects would likely be small. In particular, memory considerations won't change.